# Create script throw 404 not found on page load

Tags: javascript

I have a code in which I load some js files and activate them with create script.
This is how the code looks like

```
(function() {
    // Grab path of currently executing script
    let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    const currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
    // Remove filename
    let pathParts = currentScript.src.split('/');
    pathParts.splice(pathParts.length - 1, 1);
    // Now we have the full script path
    const PATH = pathParts.join('/');
    // Load libs accordingly
    // var EXT = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1] == 'src' ? '.js' : '.min.js';
    const EXT = '.min.js';
  
    let deferredInitRecord;

    // Delay tracking execution until everything is loaded
    window.TrackUI = {
        record (opts) {
            deferredInitRecord = function() {
                window.TrackUI.record(opts);
            };
        }
    };
  
    const loaders = ['json2', 'tracklib', 'trackui', 'html2canvas', 'spark-md5', 'crypto-js', 'fingerprint'];

    done = () => {
        loaders.shift();
        if (loaders.length === 0) {
            // Remove load.js and execute init fn
            currentScript.parentNode.removeChild(currentScript);
            if (typeof deferredInitRecord === 'function') deferredInitRecord();
        }
    };
  
    createScript = (filepath) => {
        let scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElem.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptElem.src = filepath;
        scriptElem.setAttribute("async", "");

        return scriptElem;
    };

    loadLibFile = (jsModule, callback) => {
        let lib = createScript(PATH + '/' + jsModule + EXT);
        currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(lib, currentScript);
        lib.onload = () => {
            callback();
        };
    };

for (var lib in loaders) {
        loadLibFile(loaders[lib], done);
    }
})();
```

Many times I get 404 not found when I load the script on a site and after I hit refresh the scripts load.
How could I solve this problem?